# How to pull parameter value from file stored in Git

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I just started working with ArgoCD and I have an issue I can't find the answer for.

I have a file called `clusters.yaml` in my Git repo:

```
clusters:
- name: cluster1-eu-k8s-002
  url: https://cluster1.hcp.northeurope.azmk8s.io:443
  values: 
    nameOverride: ReplaceWithThis
```

And I am using the following ApplicationSet in order to deploy Opentelemetry-collector on a bunch of clusters grouped under the label `group:dev`.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: opentelemetry-applicationset
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  generators:
  - git:
      repoURL: git@github.com:removed/cloud.git
      revision: HEAD
      files:
      - path: GitOps/argocd-apps/clusters.yaml
  - clusters:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          argocd.argoproj.io/secret-type: cluster
          group: dev
  template:
    metadata:
      name: 'opentelemetry-{{name}}'
    spec:
      project: default
      sources:
      - repoURL: https://open-telemetry.github.io/opentelemetry-helm-charts
        chart: opentelemetry-collector
        targetRevision: 0.51.3
        helm:
          valueFiles: 
            - $values/GitOps/argocd-apps/opentelemetry-collector/values/values-dev.yaml
          parameters:
            - name: nameOverride
              value: '{{ index .Clusters.values "nameOverride" }}'
      - repoURL: git@github.com:removed/cloud.git
        ref: values
      destination:
        server: '{{ server }}'
        namespace: opentelemetry
```

I am trying to replace a parameter called `nameOverride` with my value `ReplaceWithThis` from `clusters.yaml`.

ArgoCD is not deploying my app because of this line: `value: '{{ index .Clusters.values "nameOverride" }}'`

ArgoCD ApplicationSet controller logs throw some nonsense errors. I am sure I identified the problem correctly, because it works as expected if I just hardcore the string.

What exactly is the issue with the way I am trying to pull that value?

Comment: Hey, is the `clusters.yaml` mandatory for the solution? I can think of another without it

Answer (score 1):

In the [Argo CD `ApplicationSet` controller](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/application-set/), you are using `{{ index .Clusters.values "nameOverride" }}` to access the `nameOverride` value. However, `Clusters` is an array in your `clusters.yaml` file, not a dictionary. So, you should not be trying to directly index it as if it is a dictionary. (In YAML, an array (or list) is denoted by items beginning with a dash (`-`).)

The `.Clusters` field will contain an *array* of clusters from your `clusters.yaml` file, and you want to access the `values.nameOverride` field of each cluster. However, your current syntax is treating `Clusters` as if it were a dictionary that can be indexed directly with `.values`.

You should instead iterate over the `Clusters` array to access each `values` dictionary individually. You may need to use a loop structure to do this, or modify your configuration so that `values` is not nested within an array.

You can also use a different structure for your `clusters.yaml` file.
If you only have one cluster, you could structure your `clusters.yaml` file like this:

```yaml
clusters:
  name: cluster1-eu-k8s-002
  url: https://cluster1.hcp.northeurope.azmk8s.io:443
  values: 
    nameOverride: ReplaceWithThis
```

*Then*, in this case, you can directly access `nameOverride` with `{{ index .Clusters.values "nameOverride" }}`.

If you have multiple clusters and need a unique `nameOverride` for each, you could create a separate file for each cluster in your repository and adjust the `files` field in your `ApplicationSet` to match the new file structure.

That would be how a [Git file generator](https://argocd-applicationset.readthedocs.io/en/stable/Generators-Git/#git-generator-files) would be able to read each of those files, and access the `values.nameOverride` field of each cluster in their respective file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're encountering is related to the way you're accessing the `nameOverride` value from `clusters.yaml` in the `value` field of your ArgoCD ApplicationSet.

In your current configuration, you're using the following expression to access the value:

```
value: '{{ index .Clusters.values "nameOverride" }}'
```

However, the problem lies in the fact that the `values` field is defined at the top level of the `clusters.yaml` file, not nested under each cluster. Therefore, the correct path to access the value would be:

```
value: '{{ index .ApplicationSetParameters.values "nameOverride" }}'
```

By modifying the expression as shown above, you should be able to access the `nameOverride` value correctly from `clusters.yaml` and deploy your application successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue you're experiencing is likely due to incorrect usage of the index function.

In your template, you're trying to access the value of nameOverride from the clusters.yaml file using the index function. However, the way you're referencing it is incorrect.

Instead of using .Clusters.values, you should be using .Values.clusters.values. The .Values refers to the values defined in the Helm chart or the values file.

To fix the issue, modify the value field in your template as follows:

```
value: '{{ index .Values.clusters.values "nameOverride" }}'
```

This change ensures that you're accessing the correct path within the values structure.

Make sure the indentation is correct in your actual YAML file to maintain the YAML syntax.

After making this change, the value field should be able to access the nameOverride value from your clusters.yaml file correctly and substitute it during the deployment.